# while installing ubuntu facing error "root is not defined

Tags: system-installation

I have win 10 installed on my laptop.
I am trying to install ubuntu by keeping old win and partitions but facing problem "root is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation).

It has step by step procedure to install ubuntu for dual booting.

Select the protocol which has a green tick mark beside to it.

Cheers!

Comment: Please don't just link other peoples answers as your own, click the `flag` button under the question and flag it as a duplicate if you believe it has already been answered..

Comment: I tried this, but now its running only ubuntu os. It is not giving me choice of os. how do i recover it.